# Angular 2 Directive and FormGroup: to change all input text to uppercase

Tags: angular2-directives, angular2-formbuilder

Please help. I'm having trouble creating a generic directive that will always set all the inputs type text to uppercase.

below is my directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
    selector: 'input[type="text"]:not(.none-transform)',
    host:{
        '(input)':'format($event)'
    }
})
export class TextUppercase {

    constructor(private _el: ElementRef, private _control? : NgControl) {
    }

    format(value) {
        let uppercase = this._el.nativeElement.value.toUpperCase();
        this._control.control.setValue(uppercase);
    }
}
```

When I didn't set the formControl in my form, this error come:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for NgControl!
>
> Error: No provider for NgControl!

How to make the directive still working even the formControl is not set?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?